# Why PHP prints this function in reverse after swapping two lines without changing the condition

Tags: php

I have a displayNumber code which prints the input number if its greater than 1 and then calls the displayNumber function again with the number - 1.

```
function displayNumber($number) {
    if ($number >= 1) {
        echo $number;
        displayNumber($number-1);
    }

    return;
}

displayNumber(10);
```

The output would be: `10987654321`

But after swapping the echo and displayNumber lines:

```
function displayNumber($number) {
    if ($number >= 1) {
        displayNumber($number-1);
        echo $number;
    }

    return;
}

displayNumber(10);
```

The output is now: `12345678910`

I can't understand this behavior of PHP.

Comment: You swapped the order of operations, so first you reach the smallest number then you start printing the values out from smallest to largest. Simple as that.

Comment: If you have the right setup - you may be able to debug it and run it step by step.  This will show you the flow of how the code is executed.  Alternatively you can trace it through manually and see how it works.

Comment: This is how recursion works @reeshkeed You should see some examples of function recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code to make it more understandable:

```
function displayNumber($number) {
    if ($number >= 1) {
        echo $number ."<br>";
        displayNumber($number-1);
        echo $number . "---";
    }
}

displayNumber(10);
```

Output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10---
```

In the first case, values are being printed, then decremented by 1. In the second case, values are decremented by 1 and then printed.

Also, the first echo, runs every time, but this does not happen for the second echo as the function is called just before it.